# Definition of a Limit: Changing Signs

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that the precise definition for $\lim_{x\to\infty} x_k = +\infty$ is (by my textbook)

$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall k \geq K$ we have $x_k \geq \varepsilon$

but I'm having trouble changing that for $-\infty$, would it be

$\exists \varepsilon_0 > 0$ so that $\forall K\in \mathbb{N}, \exists k\geq K$ and $x_k<\varepsilon_0$

Any help understanding this would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the negation of $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_k = +\infty$ has to do with $-\infty$?

Comment: In what you have, the quantifiers are all correct, but the inner formula is not. First write down the definition of $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k = -\infty$, then negate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $ \lim_{x \to \infty}x_k = -\infty $ should be

$ \forall \varepsilon < 0$, $\exists K\in \mathbb{N} $ so that, $ \forall k\geq K$ and $x_k < \varepsilon $

Just negate the values, do not negate the statement.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you were looking for was a condition for $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=-\infty$.  In that case, you were pretty close: the answer is  $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall k \geq K$ we have $x_k <- \varepsilon$.

You didn't need to "negate" anything but just to have $x_k$ in effect change sign in the condition you had for $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_k=\infty$.   (Although maybe by "negate" you meant "make negative," which is not the usual meaning.)

Comment: I see now that negating was the incorrect thing to do, I had an earlier question that had to negate and it mixed me up